# Google Maps doesn't work on all devices while on other does.What should I do?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have an app on play store that uses a fragment for google maps.Everything was working fine but suddenly the fragment wasn't working on all devices.For example for Samsung Galaxy S8 and Xiaomi Mi Max it's working fine but for Samsung Galaxy A7(2018) it crashes when I open the map

**My xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.infractal.user.mikripoli.MapMain"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_bar"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/BottomNavView_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#fd7901"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_bar_without_back">

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**My java class**

```
  public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
  OnMapReadyCallback {


@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base, "en"));
}



@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        hideSystemUI();
    }
}

private void hideSystemUI() {
    // Enables regular immersive mode.
    // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
    // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so 
               that the
                    // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide 
             and show.
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}

 // Shows the system bars by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
private void showSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | 
  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | 
 View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}


 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);


    CustomInfoWindowAdapter adapter = new 
   CustomInfoWindowAdapter(MapActivity.this);
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(adapter);

    //Watersports Antonis
    MarkerOptions watersportsAntonis = new MarkerOptions();

    watersportsAntonis.position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(36.260148), 
    Double.valueOf(28.166458)))
            .title("Watersports Antonis")
            .snippet("")

    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_pin));

    mMap.addMarker(watersportsAntonis).showInfoWindow();


    //other activity data transfer
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bundle");
    LatLng fromPosition = bundle.getParcelable("from_position");
    LatLng coordinates = fromPosition;
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(fromPosition));
    //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates, 
            16));




    if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
        getDeviceLocation();



        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != 
           PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }


        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

        CameraUpdate zoom= CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
        mMap.moveCamera(zoom);
        mMap.animateCamera(zoom);
}

}
private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";

private static final String FINE_LOCATION = 
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = 
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;

private static final  int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;
private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);


    getLocationPermission();

    //Bottom Navigation Bar
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) 
     findViewById(R.id.BottomNavView_bar);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
    Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
    android.view.MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(0);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
     BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.ic_home:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(MapActivity.this, 
              MainMenu.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    finish();
                    break;



                case R.id.ic_contact_us:
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(MapActivity.this, 
                Mail.class);
                    startActivity(intent3);
                    finish();
                    break;
            }


            return false;
        }

      });
  }
 //device location
  private void getDeviceLocation(){

    mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.
            getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    try {
        if (mLocationPermissionGranted){

            Task location = 
      mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
            location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                   if (task.isSuccessful()){
                       Location currentLocation = (Location) 
        task.getResult();


                   }
                   else {
                       Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "unable to get  
         current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (SecurityException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityExpection:" +e.getMessage() 
 );
    }

}



private void initMap(){
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
}

private void getLocationPermission(){
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext()
            ,FINE_LOCATION )== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext()
                ,COURSE_LOCATION )== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
            initMap();
        }
        else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

        }



    }else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions,
                LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

    }        }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] 
 permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    mLocationPermissionGranted= false;

    switch(requestCode){
        case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
            if (grantResults.length>0){
                for (int i = 0; i<grantResults.length; i++) {
                    if (grantResults[i] != 
       PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
                        return;
                    }
                }

                mLocationPermissionGranted = true;

                initMap();
              }
          }
      }
  }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MapActivity.this, MapMain.class);
    startActivity(intent2);
    finish();
        }
     }
```

The google play console gave me this error

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`:

```
at gv.b (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@18385081@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):3)


  at gw.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@18385081@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):3)


  at gy.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@18385081@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):14)


  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.aj.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@18385081@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):6)


  at ga.a (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@18385081@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):22)


  at ga.run (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@18385081@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 


  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)


  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)


  at ad.loadClass (com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@18385081@18.3.85 (100400-262677519):4)


  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Google Maps SDK` version below **16.1.0**, then try adding below to your manifest:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

Refer [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/releases#2019-02-06).